# access javascript variables outside the scope of a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `jquery` function to display a menu on right click event.
I wish to access an object from the parent function inside the `callback` function.

Am using [following](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/) JQuery plugin to get the context menu.

Here is the code:

```
function OnContextMenu() {

     //alert(key + ' ' +this.Node.Content);
     var localNode = this.Node;
     alert(localNode.Content); //CORRECT NODE VALUE GETS ALERTED

        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '.Container', 
            callback: function(key, options) {
                var m = "clicked: " + key;
                 alert(localNode.Content); //ALWAYS PRINTS THE VALUE OF THE VERY FIRST NODE THAT WAS CLICKED. 
                // window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
            },
            items: {
                "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
                "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
                "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
                "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
                "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
                "sep1": "---------",
                "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see I am storing the value in a variable:

```
var localNode = this.Node;
```

and using this variable inside the `callback` function. 
Peculiar thing about this is, the `alert(localNode.Content);` inside the callback gives correct value when the menu is clicked the very first time. After that even though the `alert` of the outer function gives different values correctly, the inner callback function keeps displaying the same old value as that of the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling quite stupid right now cause I was missing a very simple thing here.
I was able to resolve this issue by declaring variable outside the function as in by using a global variable.

Below is the change:

```
 var localNode;

 function OnContextMenu() {

 //alert(key + ' ' +this.Node.Content);
 localNode = this.Node;
 alert(localNode.Content); //CORRECT NODE VALUE GETS ALERTED

    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.Container', 
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
             alert(localNode.Content); //ALWAYS PRINTS THE VALUE OF THE VERY FIRST NODE THAT WAS CLICKED. 
            // window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
            "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
            "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
            "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the `.contextMenu()` method (maybe you can point us to a URL) but it seems like the context menu gets added only once(!) for the `.Container` and for each subsequent call it will just return (because the context menu already exists for `.Container`). This is just an educated guess.

Comment: I have added the link of the jquery plugin to the question.